# Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person.hasNickname()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, google-signin

I am trying to get the Google User's Details such as their birthday, email address, nicknames, and so forth. I have enabled the Google+ API on the developers console. When I run the code that does this, it crashes with this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person.hasNickname()' on a null object reference
                                                                     at Fragments.GoogleSignUpFragment.setupPage(GoogleSignUpFragment.java:93)
                                                                     at Fragments.GoogleSignUpFragment.onCreateView(GoogleSignUpFragment.java:56)
```

Here is the code that connects to Google+ API:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount(); //Information of account is loaded here
        account.getId();
        final Person[] googlePerson = new Person[1];
        Plus.PeopleApi.load(googleApiClient, account.getId()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull People.LoadPeopleResult loadPeopleResult) {
                googlePerson[0] = loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer().get(0);
            }
        });

        DataContainer.getDataContainerInstance().setGoogleSignInAccount(account);
        DataContainer.getDataContainerInstance().setGooglePerson(googlePerson[0]);

        if (account != null ) {
            FragmentManager mgr = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = mgr.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.LoginActivityContentArea, new GoogleSignUpFragment(), "GoogleSignUpFragment");
            transaction.addToBackStack("GoogleSignUpFragment");
            transaction.commit();
        }

    }
}
```

The crash happens when I try load the next fragment with the users details into text views:

```
 private void setupPage()
{
    GoogleSignInAccount account = DataContainer.getDataContainerInstance().getGoogleSignInAccount();
    Person googlePerson = DataContainer.getDataContainerInstance().getGooglePerson();
        if (googlePerson.hasNickname()) {
            username.setText(googlePerson.getNickname());
        }
        dob.setText(googlePerson.getBirthday());
        gender.setText(googlePerson.getGender());
        location.setText(googlePerson.getCurrentLocation());
    name.setText(account.getDisplayName());
    email.setText(account.getEmail());

}
```

Is there another way of getting the google user's date of birth if the email account does not have a Google+ profile? I suspect I am getting this error because this email account may not have a Google+ profile.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with the Google API. `DataContainer.getDataContainerInstance().getGooglePerson();` has simply returned null.

Answer (score 0):

What if you wrote you code like this? Would you be at all surprised you got a null value then? You declare an array with one null value, then store that in some `DataContainer`.

```
final Person[] googlePerson = new Person[1];
DataContainer.getDataContainerInstance().setGoogleSignInAccount(account);
DataContainer.getDataContainerInstance().setGooglePerson(googlePerson[0]);

Plus.PeopleApi.load(googleApiClient, account.getId()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull People.LoadPeopleResult loadPeopleResult) {
        googlePerson[0] = loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer().get(0);
    }
});
```

Even after `onResult` is called, I don't think that updates the reference inside of `DataContainer`.

What is happening is that `onResult` might be called *after* you are starting the next Fragment, and so there is no data yet, but you go ahead and try to access it anyway.

---

I don't know what `DataContainer` is, but Singleton instances seem like a poor way to go, however here is what you should change your code to do.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        //Information of account is loaded here
        final GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount(); 
        int accountId = account.getId();

        Plus.PeopleApi.load(googleApiClient, accountId).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull People.LoadPeopleResult loadPeopleResult) {
                Person p = loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer().get(0);
                displayPerson(account, p);
            }
        });
    }
}

public void displayPerson(GoogleSignInAccount account, Person p) {

    DataContainer.getDataContainerInstance().setGoogleSignInAccount(account);  
    DataContainer.getDataContainerInstance().setGooglePerson(p);

    if (account != null ) {
        getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.LoginActivityContentArea, new GoogleSignUpFragment(), "GoogleSignUpFragment")
            .addToBackStack("GoogleSignUpFragment")
            .commit();
    }

}
```